# Joomla menu only being rendered when ?tp=1 is set

Tags: menu

I feel like I am losing my mind here, a few months ago I created several new pages on this website and had zero issues adding the menus to my new article pages, now when I am trying to add a new JEvents calendar page the menu area is blank!

I have even tried setting one of the menus to show on every page, and the menu area is still blank.

BUT : When I add the ?tp=1 command to the url the menu displays, leaving me at a bit confused about what is happening.

If anyone could chime in with ideas of how the ?tp=1 command is somehow triggering the menu to appear that would be awesome.

Please be aware that this whole issue could be a simple case of "I forgot crucial step X".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the permissions settings on the menu and articles maybe? Is one of them set to registered only or guest possibly?

?tp=1 is just a flag for the template to render the module positions on the page, it has nothing to do with whether or not a module is visible to the users. Not being able to see a module is either a permissions issue or the menu not being published to the page.

On the outside change of some very long caching issue you may wanna check that your page isn't cached by Joomla as well.